# "[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]" always returning nil

Tags: ios9, nsuuid

I am having a problem with [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] always returning nil

I am using iOS9. This call always returns 'nil' what am I doing wrong?

```
NSUUID *uuid = [NSUUID UUID];
NSString *uuidString = [uuid UUIDString];
if(uuidString == nil) uuidString =[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
if(uuidString == nil) return;
```

I've tried it both ways and it's always nil.

In the breakpointed code Info icon shows this message:

> ```
> (NSUUID *) uuid = no location, value may have been optimized out
> ```

Comment: What is the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use on all iOS device . Its working at my side from 6-9 iOS version..

```
+ (NSString *)makeUUID {
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    NSString *uuidString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return uuidString;
}
```

Comment: If the OP was running that code on an unsupported version of iOS, then surely the sky would fall in, rather than it simply returning `nul`?

Comment: I saw this in stack overflow too, and this function is always returning nil.  Im not assigning the value and waiting some time, I am getting the string and outputing it to NSLog immediately and it's always nil.  I have a call in with apple developer support because this is OBVIOUSLY something wrong with my systems current state, and there is corruption somewhere.  It's the only explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This works, it's really all I needed, a reliably unique string for managing asynchronous messages over a short period of time.  I will re-install Xcode later when I'm ready to do final testing before releasing the new version of the app.

```
- (NSString *)getUUID
{
    NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: gf_uuidLen];
    NSString *chars = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"];
    for (int i=0; i<gf_uuidLen; i++) {
        [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [chars characterAtIndex: arc4random_uniform((unsigned int)[chars length])]];
    }
    return randomString;
}
```